# Setting OnClickListener in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, android-fragmentactivity, findviewbyid

[image]

I've looked at other questions on StackOverflow with setting OnClickListener on Fragment and I tried different solutions and it didn't work. All stated I'm supposed to set getActivity(), a fragment activity but it doesn't work. How do I set an OnClickListener in a fragment then?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `How do I set an OnClickListener in a fragment then?` - by not referencing the parent Activity as you have done. `All stated I'm supposed to set getActivity()` - this is incorrect. Use `rootView.findByViewId()` assuming the view you are referencing is in the inflated view.

Comment: it's not root view.findviewbyid either. When I click on NEXTPG button, the app crashes.

Comment: As I said `assuming the view you are referencing is in the inflated view` - post the stacktrace ...

Comment: It's not an inflated view.

Comment: So you get a NPE - you can't set a click listener on something that isn't in the Fragments view hierarchy. Also in this Fragment lifecycle hook there is no guarantee that the hosting Activity has called it's onCreate hook, meaning it's content view hasn't been set yet.

Comment: I'm using TabLayout, I set multiple fragments. In one of the fragments when a button is clicked, I want the TabLayout and the Status bar to hide. That's what I'm trying to accomplish with OnClickListener.

Comment: @lbrahim, I'm trying to set an OnClickListener in a fragment Tab in TabLayout. But the code I have above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*declare variable for the button...
Declare it like this before the onCreateView method;
*/

private Button commandButton;

//Inside the onCreateView method use the below code...

commandButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.NEXTPG);

commandButton.setOnCickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@override
public void onClick(View view){
                  //your commands here
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can return also layout in OnCreateView method, so use it my code are given below.

final RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_live_tabber,container, false);

```
    Button mButton = (Button) mRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.NEXTPG);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // here you set what you want to do when user clicks your button,
        }
    });

    return mRelativeLayout;
```